# replace values in a python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to replace values in the 'mapped' dataframe with mappings in 'mappings' dataframe.

```
for column in df:
    mapped[column] = df[column].astype(str)

for i, row in mappings.iterrows():
    coln = row['colname']
    val = row['value']
    map = row['mapping']
    print 'match::' + coln + ":"+str(val)+ ":"+str(map)
    print mapped[mapped[coln]== val]
    mapped[coln].replace(str(val), str(map))

print mapped.head()
```

Although there are matching records, the values in 'mapped' dataframe is not getting replaced. How can I fix this?

Comment: `replace` is not an `inplace` operation by default. You must assign the changes back to the column of interest. So - `mapped[coln].replace(str(val), str(map), inplace=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mapped[coln].replace(str(val), str(map))`

`replace` is not inplace by default. Either pass it `inplace=True` or reassign it:

`mapped[coln].replace(str(val), str(map), inplace=True)`

or

`mapped[coln] = mapped[coln].replace(str(val), str(map))`